# Filtering ngOptions by properties of an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
//sample of data.

var combobox = new[] { 

                new { Key = 1, Value = "a[del]", isDelegate = true }, 
                new { Key = 2, Value = "b[del]", isDelegate = true }, 
                new { Key = 3, Value = "c", isDelegate = false },
                new { Key = 4, Value = "d", isDelegate = false },
                new { Key = 5, Value = "e[del]", isDelegate = true }

            };

<select ng-model="selectedFilter" id="selectedFilter"
              ng-options="item.Key as item.Value for item in ComboBox 
               track by item.Key" ng-change="loadData()">
    <option>--</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying add a `ng-if` to options for a result like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedFilter" id="selectedFilter"
       ng-options="item.Key as item.Value for item in ComboBox track by item.Key" ng-change="loadData()">
    <option value="item.Key" ng-if="item.isDelegate">{{item.Value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is just a sample. the Data came from C#

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to give a template to ng-options.

Comment: Add `| filter: {isDelegate: true} ` at the end of ng-options like this `ng-options="item.Key as item.Value for item in ComboBox track by item.Key | filter: {isDelegate: true} "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {

})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.condition = {
    isDelegate: true
  }

  $scope.combobox = [{
    Key: 1,
    Value: "a[del]",
    isDelegate: true
  }, {
    Key: 2,
    Value: "b[del]",
    isDelegate: true
  }, {
    Key: 3,
    Value: "c",
    isDelegate: false
  }, {
    Key: 4,
    Value: "d",
    isDelegate: false
  }, {
    Key: 5,
    Value: "e[del]",
    isDelegate: true
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <select ng-model="selectedFilter" id="selectedFilter" ng-options="item.Key as item.Value for item in combobox | filter:condition track by item.Key" ng-change="loadData()">
    <option value="item.Key" ng-if="item.isDelegate">{{item.Value}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using ng-repeat.

```
 <select ng-model="val2" id="selectedFilter"
                   >
                <option value="item.Key"  ng-repeat="item in combobox" ng-  
  if="item.isDelegate">{{item.Value}}</option>
            </select>
```

Check the [Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Nj3/43/)

Answer (score 0):

Filter is one option if you don't want to show options with isDelegate!=true.

```
ng-options="item.Key as item.Value for item in ComboBox track by item.Key | filter: {isDelegate: true}"
```

But if you want to show that option in the select list as disabled so that the user cannot select it use this

```
<select ng-model="selectedFilter" id="selectedFilter" ng-change="loadData()">
  <option ng-repeat="item in ComboBox" value="{{item.Key}}" ng-disabled="!item.isDelegate">{{item.Value}}</option>
</select>
```